# I want an open source project C#.Net with document for learning how design an N-tire Asp.Net web form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, architecture

I want an open source project C#.Net with document for learning how design an N-tire Asp.Net web form application.Layers are Business Layer, Data Access Layer and Web Application Layer.

I [download PetShop3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16693) but it has not documentation for learning.

Please introduce a good reference about it such as source code or eBook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the onion architecture [here](http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/a-reference-architecture-part-1/), there's also hands-on example [here](http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/a-reference-architecture-part-1/). It's about the backend, but can easily be used from within an ASP.NET MVC application.